# get deactivated computers in ad from csv list

Tags: powershell

i'm tryin to figure out which computers are deactivated. for that i provide the computer names in a csv list. i just want to output the computers which are deactivated. this is what i have. unfortunately i get all deactivated computers. but i only want that names provided in the csv

```
Import-CSV -Path "C:\pc_names" | Select -expand Name | Get-ADComputer -searchbase 'XXX' -Filter {(Enabled -eq $False)} -Properties Name, OperatingSystem | Export-CSV “C:\Temp\DisabledComps.CSV” -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: You didn't include the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely in the `Get-ADComputer` command, you specify a `SearchBase` *(assumedly an OU)*,  and a filter for all disabled computers - but never actually include the name of the PC that you piped in from the CSV, so it just returns every disabled PC under that search base.

Try something like this instead;

```
Import-CSV -Path "C:\pc_names" | Select -Expand Name | Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'XXX' -Filter {(Enabled -eq $False) -and ($_.Name)} -Properties Name, OperatingSystem | Export-CSV "C:\Temp\DisabledComps.CSV" -NoTypeInformation
```

Note the `$_.Name` in the filter.

I've probably got that filter syntax wrong - but that should be the cause.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work. script says $_.filter is not defined

Comment: Yeah, I thought I might have got that syntax wrong. You can do this instead, I've just tested quickly and it works; 

`$pcnames | % { Get-ADComputer -Identity $_ } | ? -Property Enabled -eq $False`

Note that `$pcnames` is just an array of strings in this case, e.g;

`$pcnames = @('PC1','PC2')`

Getting the filter working would be the best way of doing this though, I just don't have much time right now - this approach is much slower as it will run the Get-ADComputer command for each device individually. Hopefully this helps in the interm.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can test if the computername is to be found in an array of names using the `-Filter` parameter..

You need to first collect computer objects within your SearchBase OU and filter the disabled ones only.
Following that, you filter out the ones that can be found in the $pcNames array using a Where-Object clause:

```
$pcNames = (Import-Csv -Path "C:\pc_names.csv").Name 
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'XXX' -Filter "Enabled -eq 'False'" -Properties OperatingSystem | 
Where-Object { $pcNames -contains $_.Name } |    # or: Where-Object { $_.Name -in $pcNames }
Export-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\DisabledComps.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

<sup>Note: `Get-ADComputer` by default already returns these properties: `DistinguishedName, DNSHostName, Enabled, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, UserPrincipalName`. That means you only have to ask for the extra property `OperatingSystem` in this case</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty obvious that something like this ignores what's piped in and returns many computers.

```
'comp001' | get-adcomputer -filter 'Enabled -eq $False'
```

If you wait until the end, there is an error message:

```
get-adcomputer : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its
properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At line:1 char:13
+ 'comp001' | get-adcomputer -filter 'Enabled -eq $false'
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (comp001:String) [Get-ADComputer], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADComputer
```

You can do get-adcomputer inside a foreach loop and test Name as well:

```
$list = echo comp001 comp002 comp003
$list | % { get-adcomputer -filter 'Enabled -eq $False -and Name -eq $_' }
```